# Importing python pydriller module doesn't work in venv

Tags: python

I'm trying to import pydriller using python interpreter in venv, after installing pydriller with pip I try the following:

```
from pydriller import RepositoryMining
```

but the IDE can't recognize "RepositoryMining" and I'm getting this error:

*cannot import name 'RepositoryMining' from partially initialized module 'pydriller' (most likely due to a circular import)*

Although I can see in the "venv" the "pydriller" folder which contains a file with the class "RepositoryMining",

And after that said, I tried to install pydriller on the system (without venv) and it worked, but the problem is that I need it to be working in the project with the virtual environment, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my python file name was "pydriller.py", I needed to rename it to avoid import conflicts (hoping that this will help someone).